# Edit dictionary in a loop and append a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to edit a base dictionary in a loop and then append a list that will contain all of the edited dictionaries. No matter what I've tried, I cannot get the list to append correctly, however I can print the edited dictionary in the loop and it works fine.

What I've tried:

```
someList = []
for key, value in someDict.items():
    k=0
    while k < someVal:
        someDict["someKey"] = "someValue"+str(k)
        someList.append(someDict)
        k=k+1
            
print(someList)
```

In addition to this, I have tried putting the `while` loop on the outside and the `for` loop inside it - no luck either. I have also tried the update method for the dictionary, but it leads to the same result.

Edit - suppose the dictionary is {"key1":"value1"} and I am trying to update it to "valueN" where N is the current iteration of the loop. When I do this, someList consists of a bunch of copies of the same dictionary, all with the last edited value.

Comment: We don't know yet what went wrong.

Comment: You should include an example of an input and what your desired outputs are.

Comment: sorry - editing

Comment: Don't modify the thing you're iterating over (`someDict`) while iterating over it.

Comment: A way to avoid doing that: `for key, value in list(someDict.items()):`.

Comment: Maybe an example of how to do this then. How can I edit a dictionary in a loop and add the edited one to a list?

Comment: For me it's a mystery what the objective is. So out of curiosity - why use `while` loop for repeatedly write the same key and value: `someDict["someKey"] = "someValue"`

Comment: edited - I want the someValue to contain the index of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
   someList.append(someDict.copy())
```